# extract and modify from one ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

I need one `ArrayList<Coin>` select unique elements and add to another `ArrayList<LineItem>`. LineItem contains Coin and quantity of matching this coin at first list.

My code works but not correct and I don't know how to circumvent this restriction?

Here is check output:

```
// it's list of coin's element
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]  
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.25,name=quantity dollar]] 
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.25,name=quantity dollar]]
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]

// list of LineItem's element
[  
    LineItem [quantity=2, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]],   
    LineItem [quantity=2, theCoin=Coin[value=0.25,name=quantity dollar]],   
    LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]  
]
```

List of `LineItem` element should contain only element with unique `name`. 
If name is into list it should only update quantity of this element.
(We have only two element at Coin half dollar and quantity dollar. LineItem list must have only this two coin name and matches quantity into Coin list)

**Code:**

```
private static ArrayList<LineItem> createItems(ArrayList<Coin> coins) {
    ArrayList<LineItem> itemsList = new ArrayList<LineItem>();

    for (Coin aCoin : coins) {
        LineItem anItem = new LineItem(aCoin, 1);
        System.out.println(anItem.toString()); // print every Coin element
        if (!itemsList.contains(anItem)) {
            itemsList.add(anItem);
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done & i <= itemsList.size()) {
                Coin currentCoin = itemsList.get(i).getCoin();
                int currentQuantity = itemsList.get(i).getQuantity();
                if (currentCoin.equals(aCoin)) {
                    itemsList.get(i).setQuantity(currentQuantity + 1);
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + itemsList.toString()); // print final LineItem's list
    return itemsList;
}
```

It adds last element to `itemsList` coz this list doesn't contain element with quantity == 1. But this list has the same `Coin` value.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: In `while (!done & i <= itemsList.size())` better to use `while ((!done) && (i <= itemsList.size()))`

Comment: @tieTYT list of LineItem's element contains elements with the same Coin name and different quantity. It should be only incremented quntity for this element.

Comment: It appears that perhaps the quantity is being taken into account in your `equals` method on your `LineItem` class.  When the quantity is 1, it is found and the quantity is updated to 2.  Then it no longer matches, and a separate `LineItem` is created.  Please post your `equals` method on `LineItem`.

Comment: @Diego C Nascimento What will be if we didn't find element through all list? With `&&` - done keep being false and we never check second part of `while`

Comment: @nazar_art Why loop through the List at all? If you properly implement an equals method in LineItem to compare only the Coin aspect of LineItem, you can use `.contains( listItem )` to see if the current Coin is in the list already and `.get( indexOf( listItem ) )` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in `equals` of `LineItem` - it's check not only `Coin` but quantity too

So when you call `List.contains` it returns `false` if you processed two same coins.

Fixed version of your code can look like this

```
for (Coin aCoin : coins) {
    boolean done = false;
    for (Iterator<LineItem> it = itemList.iterator();it.hasNext() && !done) {
        LineItem currentItem = it.next()
        Coin currentCoin = currentItem.getCoin();
        int currentQuantity = currentItem.getQuantity();
        if (currentCoin.equals(aCoin)) {
            currentItem.setQuantity(currentQuantity + 1);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    if(!done) {
        LineItem anItem = new LineItem(aCoin, 1);
        itemsList.add(anItem);
    }
}
```

But I prefer to use Maps in such scenario

**Added map code**

```
Map<Coin, LineItem> map = new HashMap<Coin, LineItem>();
for (Coin aCoin : coins) {
    LineItem anItem = map.get(aCoin);
    if(anItem == null) {
        map.put(aCoin, new LineItem(aCoin, 1));
    } else {
        anItem.setQuantity(anItem.getQuantity()+1);
    }
}
itemsList.addAll(map.values());
```

but this will not work if you doesn't iverride `Coin#hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach for achieved this aim:

1. Override the equals method in Coin class, such that it returns
   true/false based on coin value.
2. iterate through array, add each coin of specific value in a map with key as the coin denomination and value as quantity (`like [0.25, 1]; [0.5, 2]` )
3. keep on summing up your quantities and replace the value of particular denomination in this map; such that at the end map looks like :

> 0.25, 3 - 3 quantity of 0.25 denomination coins
>
> 0.5, 4 - 4 quantity of 0.5 denomination coins

4 At last iterate through the map and create LineItem object to be added to ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the `equals ()` in the class LineItem

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
   return this.getCoin.equals (((LineItem)obj).getCoin);
}
```

This should allow the `contains ()` method on your list to check if the Coin is already in the List regardless of the associated quantity.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you want to achieve it's this...

You have a first list which contains:-

```
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]  
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.25,name=quantity dollar]] 
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.25,name=quantity dollar]]
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]
LineItem [quantity=1, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]]
```

But it looks like you want the result to be:-

```
[LineItem [quantity=3, theCoin=Coin[value=0.5,name=half dollar]], LineItem [quantity=2, theCoin=Coin[value=0.25,name=quantity dollar]]
```

If I were you to solve the problem I would implement the equals method on Coin which would compare both the value and the name. Although in your case just the value looks sufficient.

E.g.

```
public boolean equals(Coin coinToCompare) {
    return value.equals(coinToCompare.getValue()) && name.equals(coinToCompare.getName());
}
```

If you simply do an equals() without overidding the equals() method then it will just do a reference comparison rather than a comparison the way you want.

Also, I think you'd be better off using a HashMap with the key as the value of the coin rather than use a list which will allow duplicates.